# On Vogels with dynalite, Requested resource not found

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, vogels, dynalite

Someone could share information on how to have [vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) working [dynalite](https://github.com/mhart/dynalite)?

Here is  what I do to instanciate my DB server locally on my computer:

```
import dynalite from 'dynalite';
import packageJSON from '../package.json'

// Returns a standard Node.js HTTP server
const dynaliteServer = dynalite({ path: '../mydb', createTableMs: 50 })

dynaliteServer.listen(packageJSON.config.endpointPort, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('Dynalite started on port ' + packageJSON.config.endpointPort);
});
```

Here is what I tried to init vogels:

```
import packageJSON from '../package.json';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import vogels from 'vogels';

export default function initContext() {
  const AWSConfig = {
    accessKeyId: packageJSON.config.KEY,
    secretAccessKey: packageJSON.config.SECRET,
    region: packageJSON.config.region,
    endpoint: packageJSON.config.endpoint
  };

  //config AWD
  AWS.config.update(AWSConfig);

  //create dynamodb instance
  const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB(AWSConfig);

  //config vogels AWS
  vogels.AWS.config.update(AWSConfig);
  vogels.dynamoDriver(dynamodb);

  return {
    dynamodb,
    vogels
  };
}
```

I have defined a model and try to create it in a file named `initDB.js`:

```
initContext();

myVogelsModel.create({
    name: 'foo',
    email: 'foo@example.com',
}, function (err, model) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But it only returned me the error:

```
{ [ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found]
  message: 'Requested resource not found',
  code: 'ResourceNotFoundException',
  time: Thu Feb 09 2017 22:53:46 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid),
  requestId: 'CATZQFWSMVJKOLP0YTIMU9IEVSLJBVAB7NJB8L3EIHXCDXLT30AQ',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 0 }
C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at C:/Users/damien/Documents/workspace/myProject/src/initDB.js:23:34
    at C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\vogels\lib\table.js:193:16
    at Response.<anonymous> (C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\vogels\lib\table.js:69:14)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:355:18)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:668:14)
    at Request.transition (C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at C:\Users\damien\Documents\workspace\myProject\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
```

Any hint will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed.

The problem seems to be that I created the table (using `aws-sdk-js dynamodb.createTable` function) with a key defined as Number whereas the key of my Vogels model was `UUID` (aka a `string`).

When trying to add items in the table with vogels: it didn't work: It was confusing because with command `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:4567`: I got a correct list of Tables.

So I tried to create the table with the function `vogels vogels.createTables`. After that, calling myVogelsModel.create function worked perfectly fine.

FI: [The topic on github](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels/issues/143).